# OR condition with ON clause in join in LINQ

Tags: linq

I want to write a query in LINQ as below-

```
from tab1 in database.table1.getall()
join tab2 in database.table2.getall()
on tab1.field1 equals tab2.field1 || tab1.field2 equals tab2.field1
select new
{
   tab1.field1,
   tab1.field2,
   tab1.field3,
}
```

Please help me out that how can i write **OR(||)** while **joining 2 tables**.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to write OR conditions in join with LINQ. Possible workaround is a cross join with WHERE clause:

```
from tab1 in database.table1.getall()
from tab2 in database.table2.getall()
where tab1.field1 == tab2.field1 || tab1.field2 == tab2.field1
select new
{
   tab1.field1,
   tab1.field2,
   tab1.field3,
}
```

Comment: i might sound silly, just wanted to know that will result of this cross join be same as that of join with 'or' (that i wanted)?

Comment: @mailmehere yes, result should be same

Comment: @mailmehere welcome :) CROSS JOIN query should be slower (depends on data amount) than INNER JOIN, but this is the only way you can join on OR conditions with LINQ